# Use the gm node module to convert the color space of an image

Tags: node.js, npm, imagemagick

I am trying to use the gm node module to convert the color space of an image. I am turning the result into a buffer, not writing it to a file (if that makes a difference).  The following code is properly resizing the image, but not changing the color space (from gray to rgb):

```
gm(image).size(function(err, size) {  
    if(size.width > 1024 || size.height > 1024) {
      // Transform the image buffer in memory.
      this
        .colorspace('RGB')
        .resize(width, height)
        .toBuffer(imageType, function(err, buffer) {
          if (err) {
            next(err);
          } else {
            next(null, 'image/jpeg', buffer);
          }
      });
    }
  });
```

Any ideas or concrete examples would be greatly appreciated - my thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by *"convert colour shape"*? Change the colours? Or the shapes? Or the colourspace? Can you give an example of an image  *before* and *after* changing it?

Comment: Hi Mark, I meant Color Space - thank you

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use the raw interface? It'll look something like

```
image.convert(['inputimage.jpg','-colorspace','gray','output.jpg'],function(...)
```

Else something like this:

```
var fs = require('fs')
  , gm = require('./gm');

// change to grayscale
gm('/path/to/your/img.jpg')
.colorspace('GRAY')
.write('/path/to/result/image.png', function (err) {
  if (!err) console.log('done');
});
```

Comment: that seems correct, but the image is getting converted to a buffer, sent around a bit and eventually saved, and the color space remains.  Does converting to a buffer change anything?